# Cannot create migration script using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

(neither of the online resources helped, so I am creating a new thread.)

I am confused with errors I receive when running the following command to create migration scripts:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -v
```

I receive the following error when I have parameterless constructor for my dbcontext:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.

and when I remove the parameterless constructor, it complains I should put it back:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

I define the dbcontext as:

```cs
public class ItemContext : DbContext
{
    public ItemContext(DbContextOptions<ItemContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Item> Tools { set; get; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ToolItemEntityTypeConfiguration());
    }
}
```

The Service is defined as:

```cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddCustomDbContext(Configuration);

    var container = new ContainerBuilder();
    container.Populate(services);
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container.Build());
}

...

public static class CustomExtensionMethods
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddCustomDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ItemContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                                    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                                    {
                                        sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name);
                                        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                                    });
            options.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
        });
        return services;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation ? It's look like there is no `Program.BuildWebHost()` method

Comment: Yes, I do have that.

Comment: Hmm, your `ConfigureServices` looks strange cause it return `IServiceProvider`. Based on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.startupbase.configureservices?view=aspnetcore-2.2) it should return `void`. Nethertheless you still register `DbContext` in `services` instance therefore it should be recognized.
For test add `throw new System.Exception()` in your `ConfigureServices` method. Just for check if this method is invoked

Comment: @Gullard: Thats because he's using AutoFac, a 3rd party IoC container, which is fine (though in newer ASp.NET Core versions its prefered to use `ConfigureContainer` method

Answer (score 0):

I think this line of code

```
public ItemContext(DbContextOptions<ItemContext> options) : base(options)
{

}
```

Should change to

```
public ItemContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{

}
```

If this doesnt work for you try to register this in your Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```